# Zookeeper in docker compose not unable to access datadir

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

When running Zookeeper in docker compose it immediately fails after starting up with the error:

"Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally".

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but zookeeper-configuration, which makes it off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the two volumes in the docker-compose file resolved this issue:

```
zookeeper:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
  container_name: zookeeper
  environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  networks:
    - kafka_network
  volumes:
    - ./zoo/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
    - ./zoo/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
```